# Find path for tweepy.error.TweepError: Expecting length, unexpected value found

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-16.04, tweepy

While using tweepy I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "stream.py", line 69, in <module>
stream.filter(track=settings.TRACK_TERMS)


File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 450, in filter
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 364, in _start
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 297, in _run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 266, in _run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 323, in _read_loop
tweepy.error.TweepError: Expecting length, unexpected value found
```

my main issue currently beside not being able to find solution for the error

is that I couldn't find this path

```
build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py
```

on my machine

Any help would be very appreciated